# imported model with distorted texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, import

I downloaded a model as an FBX and OBJ, but when I open it in blender the texture is missing. I can assign it manually, but when I do it does't show up correctly, it is stretched and big or just a color. As far as I know if the model is UV mapped then the texture should be assigned automatically. I tried other objects and worked perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if it is properly UV unwrapped? It seems to pick up only one color. If you render, do you get the same result?

Comment: You can see in the UV image editor if your model is actually UV unwrapped. Also, did you import using the OBJ, or FBX, or did you try both?

Comment: Did you check if the mesh has multiple UV maps or any at all? Never assume textures carry over properly between different 3D software, but UVs should.